# Can cinnamon rolls be frozen after they are shaped?

Tags: freezing, cinnamon, rolls

Can you freeze cinnamon rolls after they are shaped? Also, about how long does it take for the dough to come to room temp?

Answer (score 1):

I would use parchment or wax paper and then aluminum foil wrapped tightly around the pan when freezing. Do not freeze more than 2 weeks in a regular freezer as they may develop freezer burn taste. Then, instead of letting them come to room temp, I would warm them in an oven for 15-20 minutes and then ice/frost them.